# Restsharp forms autentication

Tags: cookies, forms-authentication, restsharp

Is it possible? Then how?

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:58746");
var request = new RestRequest("Users/Login", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("UserName", "user");
request.AddParameter("Password", "12345");
request.AddParameter("RememberMe", true);
request.AddParameter("ReturnUrl", "http://localhost:58746");

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  var cookie = response.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName); // yeah but that will not get the cookie.
}
```

How to get to that cookie?

Comment: Hi, i am trying to understand how to implement RestSharp connecting to a formsauthentication site using Web API, can you give me some more information about what your server side endpoint looks like? At the moment, my web.config redirects me to login.aspx and then returns HTML, not sure if i need to add a login route like it looks like you have to get this working correctly

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work this way:

var cookie = response.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);